# String formatting to a specific format using string formatter

Tags: java

I need to convert the string of the form Mar 28,2012 to 28 Mar 2012 removing (,) How to do this in java?

Comment: I am not aware how to do this,as such i have posted here

Comment: Which language is your code written on?

Comment: @talnicolas i just need to convert String Mar 28,2012 to 28 Mar 2012

Comment: The question mentioned by @talnicolas should show you how to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

A couple places to look to get you started:

> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html
>
> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html
>
> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html